# How to get a field name having its instance in C#?

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a reference to an object. Not to an object hosting it. I know it is a field in some class.  I want to know the field name. So say having:

```
class A{}
class B{
   public A name1;
   public A name2;
}
class C{
   public A nameX;
}
```

I have a reference to one of the "names":

```
void do(A prop) {
    // How to get a field name of prop: name1 or name2 or nameX
}
```

How to do such thing with reflection in C#?

Comment: Do you mean you want to get all the properties in a class?

Comment: I doubt this is doable in general using managed code only (but probably with the profiler API). You would need a list of all currently alive objects and could then check them with reflection.
If you describe your use case, we might find another solution to the actual problem.

Comment: Do you have a reference to the containing object? If not, you'll find this task quite impossible -- knowing how objects (not types) refer to each other is only the domain of the garbage collector, and even that has to put in work to actually find the references. You can find all fields with the exact same *type* as the object, which isn't the same thing, but might work for your scenario (depending on what it is). Your question is akin to asking "I know there's someone thinking of me right now. I know where I am, how do I find out where that other person is"?

Comment: What if it belongs to two objects?

Comment: @MickyD: return a list

Comment: @JeroenMostert: no sadly we do not have a reference to the containing object; please see the updated question with details

Comment: @User2012384: please see the question update

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should get you all classes, then you could get the fields from each class and check the type for each against your object type. This can give you the first class.fieldname that matches your object type:

```
        string fieldName;
        IEnumerable<Type> classes = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
            .SelectMany(t => t.GetTypes())
            .Where(t => t.IsClass);

        foreach (Type cls in classes)
        {
            foreach(FieldInfo field in cls.GetFields())
            {
                if (field.FieldType == myObject.GetType())
                {
                    fieldName = cls.FullName + "." + field.Name;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: What if the class has two fields of the same type holding the same reference?

Comment: You assume that you have a reference to the object myInstance; it is not clearly stated but I read the question otherwise. Also, the OP asked about fields, not properties.

Comment: You're right Klaus, its not clearly stated but I assumed access to an instance based on the OP 'knowing it is a field' somewhere. Perhaps DuckQueen could clarify this. Regarding fields the same principle should apply as you can call GetFields() on the type and loop over the results in similar fashion.

Comment: Dear Jim, I updated the question with details. TLDR: I do not have a reference to an object hosting this field.